# Idiomatic translation of "passive aggressive"

Tags: translation, equivalent-phrase

The English term "[passive aggressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive-aggressive_behavior)" is generally used to describe non-overt displays of aggression, such as resistance, poor attitude, [posting silly workplace notices](http://www.passiveaggressivenotes.com/) or other behaviours that indirectly express hostility to the target.

However, I was unable to find an idiomatic translation. Google returns a few answer sites ([1](https://sg.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101123103322AAh29Rl),[2](https://taiwanease.com/en/forums/how-does-one-say-passive-aggressive-in-chinese-t12218.html),[3](http://www.forumosa.com/taiwan/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=85897)) which return examples that sound like machine translations, and which also sound partly like oxymorons due to their different connotations in Chinese. For example, `被动攻击` and `消极攻击` were all given as examples, but they do not appear to make sense, and sound like machine translations.

How would one idiomatically translate the phrase into Chinese?

Comment: see jukuu for not machine translated examples, involving "passive aggressive personality, (also underachievement）"  all using 消极攻击

Comment: can you give a couple of examples of when and how you'd want to use the term in Chinese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To literally translate " passive aggressive" as 「被動攻擊」or 「消極攻擊」cannot capture the essence of this phrase. It is better to use interpretation that truly express the meaning of it.

My choice is " 陰損"

> [http://tw.ichacha.net/hy/陰損.html](http://tw.ichacha.net/hy/%E9%99%B0%E6%90%8D.html)
>
> ①陰險尖刻：說話～。

Answer (score 1):

I would say 被动攻击 and 消极攻击 are the correct term. It sounds strange and machine like because it is so rarely used. I would say this is something related to psychology and it is one area that is just beginning to be explored or studied in the Chinese society.

Coming from a Chinese background, I hear a lot of "消极" or "被动" describing a person, but I guess we only thought of it as a personality trait rather than a "Passive aggressive" behaviour. But I think as China is exploring in this area more and more, more people will come to know this term "被动攻击/消极攻击", and it won't sound so machine like anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think `被動攻擊` and `消極攻擊` are both appropriate for passive aggressive. Because it looks like a proper noun in psychology, not a well-known noun in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider it's 消极敌对 or 消极仇视 in the context of hostile working environment or behavior at workplace. Reasons for people behave that way could be insecure, incompetent, over-confident at different times.